# Как опубликовать Google таблицы средствами Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Вручную это делается через Файл/Публикация в Интернете.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=ru
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать средствами Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, такой возможности нет.

Максимум, что можно сделать в этой ситуации - это отправить feature request, из приложения Таблиц.

По моему личному мнению, это как-то небезопасно.